# Has pandemic caused shortage of bikes?

Tags: shopping, price

I am in the market for new road bike.  My local bike shop is all sold out and also I noticed on Giant website the Giant escape which I bought back in 2014 for $350 is now over $500 for the same model with not much improvement?

Is right now a bad time to buy a new bike?

Comment: There is never a bad time to buy a new bike.

Comment: Is it a bad time, can't say.  But yeah global supply chains of "everything" are stretched right now.  Demand for bikes has gone through the roof in the last 18months as large chunks of the world have had nothing better to do, then supply is stretched because of shipping constraints, then manufacturing of bikes and components have been at probably an all time low

Comment: Inflation is a thing - $350-$500 in 7 years is about average.  This is different to covid-induced stock/supply problems.

Comment: Possibly relevant link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrkOYlIPcQU

Comment: Another interessant link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cukx_BSQ0Ww

Comment: Comparing the price of a $350 bike purchased in 2014 with a $450 bike purchased in 2021? According to www.usinflationcalculator.com there has been a cumulative rate of inflation of 15.3% meaning that the same item purchased in 2014 for $350 would cost $403.62 today.

Comment: @Criggie yes but entry level cars has gotten better without going up in price

Comment: Remember valuations are considered off-topic, so don't focus only on price please.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  A couple of things have happened with the pandemic. The supply chain, from manufacturing though logistics to the retail have been disrupted.

The big disruption is logistics, impacting the input to the manufacturing slowing production, along with disruption to staffing and all that goes with it.  Once the product has been manufactured it needs delivering to the markets, again, shipping world wide is a cot case. Shipping containers from China and Japan (where most bike parts are made) to, well, nearly everywhere, is difficult, suffering long delays and inflated prices.

Fewer bikes are making to the retailers at higher prices, along with the increase in demand for bicycles because people have nothing better to do has driven list prices sky high, with no need for retailers to offer the usual seasonal discounts.

Comment: Why "the increase in demand for bicycles because people have nothing better to do"? In Europe (I'm not following that kind of news elsewhere), there has been a strong push towards "active mobility", as fewer people are willing to take public transport. Also to fight pollution, and "space requirement for parkings", car use is also severely discouraged. More people are turning into cycling, and there are incentives to buy bikes (up to 1.5k€ to replace a car by an ebike in France for example — why would a seller discount if there's a subsidy?). It's a good thing, not "nothing better to do" ;)